# Filter data from a collection

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a collection of a Parent class. Parent class has an ID property and some other class property. So, I would like to fetch those child property values on the basis of the `Parent ID`. I am able to fetch an item of the collection but I need a single value from that item. Below is my code:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Child MyChild { get; set; }

}

public class Child
{
    public string abc { get; set; }
    public string xyz { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var d = new List<Parent>();
        d.Add(new Parent
        {
            Id = 1,
            MyChild = new Child()
            {
                xyz = "XYZ one",
                abc = "ABC one"
            }
        });

        d.Add(new Parent
        {
            Id = 2,
            MyChild = new Child()
            {
                xyz = "XYZ two",
                abc = "ABC two"
            }
        });

        for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++)
        {
            var xyzValueOfParentIdOneValue = d.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id = 1) // Here, I want to get XYZ property value of Parent ID 1.
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What **exact** output do you want?

Comment: I want "XYZ one" value of xyz property

Comment: I also need to check whether this collection has a specific parent id or not. if not, I will return a default value (something like "0")...That is why I tried to use SingleOrDefault()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this

```
var xyzValueOfParentIdOneValue = d.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1)
                                       ?.MyChild
                                       ?.xyz;

if (xyzValueOfParentIdOneValue != null)
{
   ......
}
```

Or

```
var foundItem = d.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);

if (foundItem != null && foundItem.MyChild != null)
{ 
  var xyzValueOfParentIdOneValue = foundItem.MyChild.xyz;
}
```

These two above codes are completely similar.

Comment: Because the question is used loop. I thought he needs a loop to do something. I changed it. @mjwills

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want to access the `MyChild` property of the `Parent`, like:

```
        var parent = d.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
        var xyz = parent.MyChild.xyz;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to return a default value "0" if the Parent Id doesn't exist, you could use

```
var xyzValueOfParentIdOneValue = d.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == idToSearch)?
                                  .MyChild?
                                  .xyz ?? "0";
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.